# BufferedReader.readLine() regresa null como resultado

Tags: java

Estoy escribiendo un método para contar el numero de lineas en un documennto de text en Java.

```
public int numeroLineas(FileReader re) throws IOException {

    String str;

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(re);
    Vector<String> v = new Vector<String>();

    while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
        v.add(str);
    }

    if (v != null) {
        br.close();
    }

    System.out.println("Lineas: " + v.size());
    return v.size();
}
```

No se puede acceder al ciclo `While` porque br.ReadLine() regresa `null`.

El resultado en la consola es siempre :

```
Lineas: 0
0
```

Comment: o sea que br no recibe un archivo abierto.. y probaste que el archivo se abriera de alguna forma?

Comment: Si, probe escribir algo en el archico con un BufferedWriter y escribe sin problemas.

Comment: Tienes declarado un throw en el método. Cuando ejecutas este método ¿Capturas este trhow y muestra algo o solo captura? Puede ser que no este leyendo bien el fichero y por ahí este oculto un mensaje. Un int no puede devolver null por lo tanto devuelve 0, pero si no me equivoco BufferedReadear te debería mostrar NullPointerException en la consola.

Comment: Si lo que quieres es contar las lineas, para que consumir memoria guardandolas. Mejor incrementa un contador en cada ejecucion dentro del while

Comment: @AbrahamTS Aun así le debería funcionar pero el problema es que no lee el archivo o eso parece.

Comment: Corrijo mi comentario anterior debe tirarte `FileNotFoundException` y `IOException`. Probe tu código en una clase y lo mande a invocar y me funciono todo perfecto.

Comment: @RafaelAngelRamirezEstrada Ya se que deberia funcionar. Sin embargo el comentario no esta de mas. Es mas eficiente utilizar un contador o incluso leer directamente caracter por caracter y aumentar el contador cuando se encuentre el caracter de fin de linea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema se resolvio al cambiar el parametro FileReader del método a uno de tipo File, tenia dos métodos que venian llamados en el `main`.

```
File file = new File("C:/Users/bryan/Desktop/Apelli.txt");

FileReader f = new FileReader(file);

    Lettura writer;
    writer= new Lettura ();
    System.out.println(writer.letteraOrdine(f));
    System.out.println(writer.numeroRighe(f));
```

Los dos usaban el mismo FileaReader, no se si eso causaba el conflicto.
El método modificado:

```
public int numeroLineas(File f) throws IOException {

    String str;

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
    Vector<String> v = new Vector<String>();

    while ((br.readLine()) != null) {
        str = br.readLine();
        //System.out.println("str " + str);
        v.add(str);
    }

    if (v != null) {
        br.close();
    }

    System.out.println("Lineas: " + v.size());
    return v.size();
}
```

Despúes de haber modificado los métodos los llame así:

```
File file = new File("C:/Users/bryan/Desktop/Apelli.txt");

    Lettura writer;
    writer= new Lettura ();
    System.out.println(writer.letteraOrdine(file));
    System.out.println(writer.numeroRighe(file));
```

Y funciono sin problemas.

Comment: Justo estaba revisando eso. Tuve que usar esta linea para invocar:  `int a =clase.numeroLineas(new FileReader(new File("c:/a.txt")));`